# Default portrait changes to Landscape by itself on IPad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have set the default device orientation to "Portrait" in info.plist. When I look into IPad, the app turns to landscape mode. How can I fix it to Portrait mode? It's working fine on iPhone.

[image]

Comment: What is your application target devices? `iPhone` or `Universial`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings, one for iPhone and one for iPad, my guess is that you have chosen the correct settings for iPhone but did not change the settings for the iPad.

Perform the same setting for iPad and it will work.

You can read more about it in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=vsmac

I hope this information will help you!